# Select indices from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indices

I have two tables (.csv) say table1 and table2. In table1 we have 5000 rows and two columns: ID (numerical) and employment_situation (categorical). In table2 we have 7000 rows and two columns: ID (numerical) and score (numerical). All the subjects in table1 are within table2 with the same ID, probably in different order.

What I would like to do is create a list with the scores from the 5000 subjects from table1 and then find the average score for each category in employment_situation.

How can I do this in pandas? I want to use the ID column from table1, with those values select the indices from table2 which correspond to the IDs extracted from table1, and with those indices create the wanted list of scores. Thanks

Comment: Start with `merge`?

Comment: I think you should use the following, table1.merge(table2, how='left', on='id'), I'd recommend providing code that you've tried so we can give better answers. This works very similarly to a vlookup in Excel if you know how to use that.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left').groupby('employment_situation', as_index=False)['score'].mean()`